# Как обмануть сканер портов?

Tags: linux, iptables

Возможно ли сканерам портов вернуть будто порт закрыт, но на самом деле он открыт??

Comment: Как вариант использовать port knocking: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking, http://ashep.org/2010/zashhita-sistemy-pri-pomoshhi-port-knocking/

Comment: Главное как то засечь сканер. Если он тупо перебирает порты на вашем ip - то это возможно, но если он (а так делают многие) проверяет один конкретный порт на множестве ip то на своем единственном адресе вы его никак не отличите от обычного коннекта. Посмотрите в сторону snort, например

Comment: @kmv, хороший же ответ, оформите его. А вместе с `one time sequence` будет ещё сильнее сокрытие.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вынесено из комментария

---

Один из вариантов скрытия портов от утилит сканирования и несанкционированных подключений - механизм [port knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking).
Суть его в том, что изначально порт защищаемого сервиса закрыт файрволом, демон port knocking'a ожидает получения пакетов на определенные порты в заданной последовательности,
после чего открывает порт сервиса для доступа извне.

Мануалы по настройке:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Port_knocking
- http://ashep.org/2010/zashhita-sistemy-pri-pomoshhi-port-knocking/

Преимущества/недостатки port knocking - вопрос обсуждаемый, но в любом случае, этот механизм нужно рассматривать как часть системы безопасности, а не ее единственный элемент.

Основные неудобства в использовании:

- Требуется клиент для предварительной отправки последовательности пакетов перед подключением.
- Нет прямой поддержки в ядре Linux (хотя есть варианты решения целиком на iptables).
  Демон port knocking'a - это точка отказа, проблемы функционирования демона приведут к проблемам с доступом к защищаемым сервисам.
- Рекомендуется периодически менять последовательность "стуков".

Answer (score 3):

Такое возможно. Nmap, например, использует различные техники сканирования (через zombie, xtree), кроме того сами сервисы могут отличаться поведением или ждать специальных пакетов, поэтому nmap может допускать `false-positive` ошибки. Много зависит от глубины анализа nmap. См. также [статью](https://xakep.ru/2013/11/27/easy-hack-176/)

Но, я полагаю, это скорее случайное поведение. Сделать его более вероятным можно, выбрав нестандартный порт.